# Distribute JSON data into different HTML elements with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am parsing a JSON Object and using a foreach loop to output the data.

```
function do_api_call() {
  $place_id = get_theme_mod('place_id_setting_field');

  $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" . $place_id . "&key=myapikey";
  $data = file_get_contents($url);

  $rev = json_decode($data, true);
  $reviews = $rev["result"]["reviews"];
  foreach($reviews as $review) {
    $review_snippet = $review["text"];
    echo $review_snippet . '<br>';
  }
}
```

This works fine when I call it within an HTML element with:

```
<?php echo do_api_call() ?>
```

The short of it is that I get back 5 reviews from this loop and I need each review to go to their own html element in a different file called `reviews.php`, this file contains 5 unique bootstrap cards with a `div` that needs to hold a unique review so I need to output a unique review into each of these cards.

Like so:

```
<div> review 1 text </div>
<div> review 2 text </div>
<div> review 3 text </div>
<div> review 4 text </div>
<div> review 5 text </div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, btw why are you assigning `$review["text"]` to `$review_snippet` and then printing it, why don't you just print `$review["text"]`?

Comment: im pretty new to php, my question is, this foreach loop outputs 5 reviews from the object, i need to output them each seperately into 5 different html elements.  Right now, when I output that function I get all 5 reviews in one html element.

Comment: what's wrong with `echo '<div>'.$review_snippet.'</div>';`? You already know how to add a `<br>`, so there's no difference to add a `<div>`

Comment: What's wrong with `echo '<div>'.$review["text"].'</div>'`?

Comment: @MehdiBounya we even got the same wording!

Comment: im sorry, im not explaining myself correctly.  The output is going to into a different file.  There are 5 locations in that file where i need a unique review in each from 1-5

Comment: then you'll have to store the data in between or fetch it dynamicly when you need it. Until we don't know the exact details we cannot answer better than we did....

Comment: @Jeff what a coincidence! OP, you can't do that with a loop, if there are always 5 rows, access them manually like this: `$reviews[0]`

Comment: can i call a variable from a function that is in a different file?

Comment: yes. the files get 'put together' before they are executed.

Comment: so then i should not use a loop at all, instead just reference the different indexes.  Should I leave my code inside a function?

Comment: Yeah, maybe just return the $reviews (in the function) and access them as Mehdi said.

Comment: calling the variables, is not producing any output

Comment: <?php echo $review['text'] ?> is what I tried inside the html element in my other php file

Comment: You need to store the function inside a variable, and then inside the function instead of `echo'ing, `return` the data.

Comment: so $api_var = my_function(); then in that same file call <?php echo $api_var ?> ?

Comment: Is it a known number of reviews, or do you have an unknown amount to content with in different places in your HTML page you are constructing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access a direct review with `$rev["result"]["reviews"][0]` (for the first) `$rev["result"]["reviews"][1]` (for the second) etc. So you can pass which review as a function arg.

However to cut down on re-loading an external source with every call of the function, you may want to do the data loader outside the function:

```
$place_id = get_theme_mod('place_id_setting_field');
$url     = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='. 
            $place_id .'&key=myapikey';
$data    = file_get_contents($url);
$rev     = json_decode($data,true);
$reviews = $rev['result']['reviews'];// this is now setup and ready to use
```

And then setup the anonymous function using the global (php 5.3+):

```
$get_review = function ($r) use (&$reviews) {
    if (isset($reviews[$r])) {
        return '<div>'. $reviews[$r]['text'] .'<div>';
    }
    return '';// no review to return
};
```

Then down in your html where you want to begin outputting them, you call it as such (note the $ is intentional with anonymous functions assigned to variables):

```
<body>
    blah blah other stuff
    <?php echo $get_review(0);?>
    more blah
    <?php echo $get_review(1);?>
</body>
```

Or if you need to loop on how many reviews you have:

```
<body>
    <?php for($r=0;$r < count($reviews);$r++) { echo $get_review($r); } ?>
</body>
```

If you are afraid of using anonymous functions as I have above, you can adjust it to this instead:

```
function get_review ($r,&$reviews) {
    if (isset($reviews[$r])) {
        return '<div>'. $reviews[$r]['text'] .'<div>';
    }
    return '';// no review to return
}

// call it as thus
echo get_review(0,$reviews);
echo get_review(1,$reviews);
// etc
```

---

**Class Method:**

Of course you COULD also turn this into a small class object, where you first `load_api`, then `get_review` as methods of the class:

```
class Reviews {
    public static $reviews;

    public static function load_api() {
        $place_id = get_theme_mod('place_id_setting_field');
        $url     = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='. 
                    $place_id .'&key=myapikey';
        $data    = file_get_contents($url);
        $rev     = json_decode($data,true);
        self::$reviews = $rev['result']['reviews'];// this is now setup and ready to use
    }
    public static function get_review($r) {
        if (isset(self::$reviews[$r])) {
            return '<div>'. self::$reviews[$r]['text'] .'<div>';
        }
        return '';// no review to return
    }
}

// to initialize
Reviews::load_api();

// to call and output
echo Reviews::get_review(0);
```